# Cassandra throws ReadTimeout exception for LOCAL_QUORUM queries when one of three replicas goes down

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have cassandra cluster of 3 nodes in one dc. Each keyspace is configured with replication factor 3.

All my queries are executed with LOCAL_QUORUM consistency. If one of my nodes goes down (for test purposes I just kill it via shell command) during read request, this request fails with ReadTimeoutException, saying that only one replica responded (2 expected), but all consequent read requests return data.

In my understanding this error shouldn't happen, because two nodes are still running and it should be enough for LOCAL_QUORUM consistency. How can I fix the exception?

Comment: Execute your query with `tracing on` paste the log

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you using? At first glance I would expect `speculative_retry` to mitigate that on the server side:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/rapid-read-protection-in-cassandra-2-0-2

Comment: I'm using 2.2.8 version and speculative retry is configured to 99 percentile.
I'm puzzled why speculative retry fails in this case.

Comment: Even when I set speculative retry to ALWAYS I'm still getting this error